# Can I specify particular LTS release in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades?

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, hp

I have an  HP DL360 G4 server. I currently run 10.04 LTS Server on it. However, to install 10.04, I had to first install 8.04 LTS and then use "do-release-upgrade" to upgrade to 10.04, as the G4 will not boot the 10.04 CD image.

I set "prompt" in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades to "lts", which looks for the next LTS.

I'm planning on getting another DL360 G4, but it may not be till after 12.04 LTS comes out.

Is there a way to specify 10.04 LTS in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades instead of having it install 12.04? I need to run 10.04 on both machines.

I realize that the DL360 G4 is not Ubuntu certified, but it is all that my budget allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from 8.04 will only get you to 10.04, not to 12.04.
You don't have to install 12.04, nor should it be offered as upgrade, not before having upgraded to 10.04.

Comment: Shoot, I forgot that Ubuntu upgrades in "steps". Thank you for reminding me of this!